# How should a Model be implemented in iOS using Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, model

> EDIT: Although the answers are teaching me things, I still have no
>   idea how I might "implement" a model. Can anyone give me an example as
>   to how I would create a simple model class that has a few basic
>   functions that make calls to NSUserDefaults or JSON web calls and how
>   I would access this from ANY of my view controllers?

I am just beginning iOS development and have come to the point where my app will require a Model to interact with the overall data flow between controllers, but am unsure as to how they should be implemented properly.

I understand that the View's are in the storyboard, and the Controllers are the classes associated with those views.

What is the proper way to implement a central Model for an app? Do i create a class (ie "MyModel.h/.m") and then import it from all of my view controllers?

I also see people using a UINavigationController->RootViewController as their model, is this viable?

I have googled this question and searched stack overflow for a few hours, but am now resorting to a new question.

> EDIT: Although the answers are teaching me things, I still have no
>   idea how I might "implement" a model. Can anyone give me an example as
>   to how I would create a simple model class that has a few basic
>   functions that make calls to NSUserDefaults or JSON web calls and how
>   I would access this from ANY of my view controllers?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vnkNUoRtk1E

Comment: +1 good question.. there are many ways to implement MVC in iOS but i have never wondered which is appropriate way ..

Comment: what i am sure is that using rootviewcontroller as model is not viable

Comment: Accessing Core Data from my controllers are not enough for me, i want a central model that contains functions that can be called from any controller that is present.

Answer (score 7):

In iOS, `a model (MyModel class) is usually a subclass of NSObject or in the case of Core Data (an iOS framework that helps save data to a database locally on the device) NSManagedObject.` As with any model object it contains instance variables and **getter / setter methods**. Most object-oriented languages have a mechanism to provide **encapsulation**, in iOS a *property* provides encapsulation and the keyword *synthesize* automatically generates the getter and setter methods.

`View is subclass from *UIView* which provides the capability for handling touch events and drawing.`
 The **UIKit framework** contains classes to draw typical interface elements such as tables (lists), buttons, textfields, sliders and more.

`Controller is generally a subclass of **UIViewController** that manages a view,` it is also responsible for responding to delegation messages and target-action messages.you can have a UITableViewController which is a subclass of **UIViewController** that manages a **UITableView**

`TabBar and Navigation View Controllers` manages an array of view controllers, but  Navigation VC manages VC as a “`stack`” data structure and `yes it is a viable usage`

please have a look at [Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html) in ios apple library resource for further reference and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010443) is a apple sample code to understand how to create a network application using the Model-View-Controller design pattern

[this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) tutorial teaches you how to get started with **JSON** , try integrating FB in your app for understanding JSON as its fun and easy

start coding **NSUserDefault** in your app for example

```
// create a standardUserDefaults variable
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[standardUserDefaults setObject:@"mystring" forKey:@"string"];
```

[here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/nsuserdefaults_iphone-sdk/) is a good tutorial i started with..

happy coding :)

Comment: Your answer is extremely helpful and I enjoyed all of the links that you pointed me towards, but I can't award as the accepted answer because I am looking to find how I would "implement" a central model class that can be accessed from any view.

Comment: @Deminetix: Did you find your desired solution for this question? It will help if you share!!